# can't download xcode from appstore?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, mac-app-store

I have Mac lion and I have Xcode 4.2 installed (downloaded from appstore for free).

Today I wanted to upgrade to 4.3.2. Then I searched Xcode from appstore, on the Xcode page, it says "Free", then I click on free, the button turns to green with text "Install App".

After click "Install App", it start downloading, but it's so slow and I had to take the computer out for a while, then I paused the download and shut down the computer.

Then, after I came back, when I return back to appstore, there's no resume downloading. When I search Xcode again, on the Xcode page, it says "Free", when I click on "Free", the button turns into Gray with text "Install", when I click on "Install", nothing happens.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to Mac's App Store -> Purchases tab and see the progress of your download. It should show Paused/Running etc.

Comment: Thank you, I found it! But now the problem  is, when I click on Resume, nothing happens. Then I deleted it (there's a cross button beside, when I click on it, it was removed from purchases). Then I click on "Install App" from appstore again, but it still shows 1.44G of 1.53G, seems that it's not deleted at all. Any hints?

Comment: Hmm,I guess you will have to let it continue from there. I did the same when I hit this problem. Worked for me, but the download took a very long time.

Comment: Pressing the "X" button from the purchases page just hides the app so it doesn't show there or in the updates page.

Comment: Note for future readers: Mac App Store is still buggy and if the Update button near app name under Updates tab seems not to respond to your clicks, check Purchases tabs. Maybe it's already being downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

If u have downloaded the xcode from the app store then try upgrading it from 'Updates' tab
->last tab(that tab will have even badge indicating updates available for installed/purchased apps).

[image]

Moreover goto LAUNCHPAD, u should find the status of downloading app as PAUSED. 
[image]

Click on that app then it will resume download.